# CreateProcessWithLogon returns Function not supported

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, process

I'm trying to start a program that starts another program as another user with the Win32 function CreateProcessWithLogon on a Windows 7 system but it returns error 120 which stands for *function not supported*.

If I run the program in the command it works correctly.  If I on the other hand start the program with ShellExecute then I get the error.

Cmd Line -> Start Program A ->  Program A executes CreateProcessWithLogon.  OK
32 bit program -> Start Program A -> Program A executes CreateProcessWithLogn.  ERROR

```
        if (!CreateProcessWithLogonW(L"username", L"domain", L"password",
        LOGON_NETCREDENTIALS_ONLY, L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe", L"iexplore",
        NULL, NULL, NULL,
        &si, &pi))
        DisplayError(L"CreateProcessWithLogonW");
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want starts program **as another user** not use `LOGON_NETCREDENTIALS_ONLY` flag - use `LOGON_WITH_PROFILE` instead.

```
    STARTUPINFO si = { sizeof(si) };
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    if (CreateProcessWithLogonW(L"username", L"domain", L"password", LOGON_WITH_PROFILE, 
        L"C:\\windows\\notepad.exe", L"notepad.exe", 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
    {
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    }
```

if you use flag `LOGON_NETCREDENTIALS_ONLY`

> The system does not validate the specified credentials.

so really you not need provide real name or password. because system not do real login but

> The new process uses the same token as the caller, but the system
>   creates a new logon session within LSA

so this logon type clone caller current token but specify new logon session in it. your program will be run **as same user** (*SID* , groups, privileges) but in separate logon session

only one trick need, not documented - *lpUsername* must be in UPN format - containing **@** symbol.

so code must be like this:

```
    STARTUPINFO si = { sizeof(si) };
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    if (CreateProcessWithLogonW(L"@", 0, 0, LOGON_NETCREDENTIALS_ONLY, 
        L"C:\\windows\\notepad.exe", L"notepad.exe", 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
    {
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    }
```

as result will be created new LogonSession with [`NewCredentials`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380129(v=vs.85).aspx) as [`SECURITY_LOGON_TYPE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380129(v=vs.85).aspx) , `AuthenticationPackage == Negotiate`

Comment: Thanks for the info but LOGON_WITH_PROFILE produced the same error.

Comment: @Karlth i of course tested own code (om win7 too) and it work well. if run exactly your code snippet - i got another error - `ERROR_INVALID_LOGON_TYPE` which is gone if remove `LOGON_NETCREDENTIALS_ONLY` or use it with L"@" as username. if you have another error - you need debug. may be error even in your process, but faster of all you need set bp in `svchost.exe -k netsvcs` process on `seclogon.SlrCreateProcessWithLogon` and debug it - http://i.imgur.com/euZrIio.png or may be debug lsass.exe if error returned by `LsaLogonUser`